# Word for "to remove the soul" like decapitate/behead "to remove/cut off the head"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, terminology

What is the single word/verb for "to remove the soul of/from"? 
It would be like *decapitate/behead* meaning "to remove/cut off the head of/from".

Example sentence (in fiction):

> The creature _______ him and turned him into an empty shell of flesh and blood, shortly destined to become dust.

**Dispirit** is used figuratively and means to lower the spirit or enthusiasm of.

Soul is *anima* in Latin but there is no such word as **deanimate**. 
*Animate* means "to breathe life into, to endow with life".

I've found **disanimate** but it means "to deprive of life or consciousness; to render lifeless or inanimate; to kill" per *OED*. It doesn't have the strong sense of removing soul and doesn't fit in the context.

I've also found **desoul** used as the name of a spell in the game *[Shining](https://shining.fandom.com/wiki/Desoul)*.

> Desoul is a powerful spell that is often cast by dark characters. It has a chance to take the target's soul thus knocking them out of the battle. It can also be used by items like Kane's Sword of Darkness.
>
> [image]

*Desoul* is not in any credible dictionaries nor *OED* (which likes to list even obsolete words). Is it the best we can get?

Am I missing any other words or more established words (in fictional works or maybe in some dark magic context)?

Comment: It's all fictional anyway, so how about [***zombify**?*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/zombify)

Comment: Not sure if this will do, but have you considered _zombify_? Apparently, zombies are soulless.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: [Absolutely!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22animectomy%22) *They had gone through the humiliation, the stripping, the public **excision of their souls,** the **animectomy.***

Comment: The question presupposes a *death-like* action. Another view is the theosophists' notion of *astral projection*. Not a single word but another way of thinking about the question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astral_projection

Comment: A single word? Would you consider a word that would fit in "the creature ____ his soul?" I have answers for that with historical usage, many of which can be found in the OED (according to the dictionary I'm using).

Comment: @Laurel Then, there is *remove*  Are there any verbs more closely associated with removing the soul?

Comment: Wiktionary is arguably the most up-to-date dictionary of English.

Comment: The words I'm looking at are defined along the lines of "of the soul: separate from the body", some have other definitions, some are very obscure even in their time and probably would have other definitions otherwise. There's one word that I'd roughly translate to saying the soul was "de-bodied", which has historical currency but is otherwise unintelligible to a modern audience.

Answer (score 3):

**desoul** (v.)

> (Transitive) To strip of a soul.
>
> 1998, Shirley Boteler Mock, *The Sowing and the Dawning*, page 38: The
> crucial shared features are desouling, release of the soul from its
> “vessel,” and travel by transformation from one level of existence to
> another through a portal linking levels.
>
> 2005, Robert B. Clarke, *An Order Outside Time* […] there followed
> centuries of the exploration of matter that has led to the
> matter-worship of our modern age and the desouling of the world. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desoul)

---

> On the contrary, he said, employing a line of reasoning that would
> reappear again and again in the later history of natural theology and
> especially in the post-Darwin period, natural philosophers could
> **desoul** the natural world all they wanted: it only added to the staggering marvel of its so-called machinery and made it all the more
> impossible to account for its origin without God, since ... [Wallace
> Marshall; *Pluritanism and Natural Theology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Puritanism_and_Natural_Theology/CUacDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desoul%22&pg=PT127&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

> The latter point is important in the light of René Fulop-Miller's
> charge in The Mind and Face of Bolshevism that the effect of Bolshevik
> mechanisation was to '**desoul**'... art. [Jonathan Pitches; *Science and
> the Stanislavsky Tradition of Acting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Science_and_the_Stanislavsky_Tradition_o/0ByAAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=desoul&pg=PT112&printsec=frontcover) (2005)

> The weakest point in any of them is the effort to **desoul** mankind.
> [Gibson Andrews; *The Story of Creation*](http://o5EXAAAAYAAJ) (1900)

> Befitting a paganist worldview, Gumilev is inclined to “ensoul” nature
> and “naturalize” or “**desoul**” the human. [Mikhail Epstein; *Ideas
> Against Ideocracy*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ideas_Against_Ideocracy/hiE8EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desoul%22&pg=PA46&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> “I'm surprised it didn't **desoul** the mother,” he answered. [Harry
> Turtledove; *The Case of the Toxic Spell Dump*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Case_of_the_Toxic_Spell_Dump/oWZqCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desoul%22&pg=PT99&printsec=frontcover) (2015)

> What was needed according to Jung's viewpoint was both an appreciation
> of the mythos perspective in a regrettably demythologized and
> **desouled** world as well as accountability to the rationally critical functions represented by the logos point of ... [Walter
> Shelburne; *Mythos and Logos in the Thought of Carl Jung*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mythos_and_Logos_in_the_Thought_of_Carl/yV-ZE8pyZjkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desouled%22&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover) (1988)

> In fact , the process of history has involved a devitalizing and
> **desouling** reminiscient of Max Weber's notion of disenchantment.
> ...
> Not only does the mechanistic viewpoint disenchant the organic
> world, but also a certain devaluation, despiritualization, and
> **desouling** of the world must have preceded that viewpoint's emergence. [Michael Barber; *Guardian of Dialogue*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Guardian_of_Dialogue/rALrAeL_iV4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desouling%22&pg=PA26&printsec=frontcover) (1993)

> Therefore, after touching on the problem of isolation, Scheler directs
> the full force of his criticism against the **desouling** of subhuman
> nature and opposes it with the theory of the mind as the
> characteristic distinguishing man from the animal. [E. Voegelin and K.
> Vondung; *Race and State*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Race_and_State/y5nhoISw64YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desouling%22&pg=PA24&printsec=frontcover) (1997)

> The moral appears to be the desiccating, **desouling** influence of
> the conception of a world without a personal God or a definite moral
> law. [*Journal of Religious Psychology*, vol. 2, p.140](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_of_Religious_Psychology_Includin/njcOAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22desouling%22&pg=PA140&printsec=frontcover) (1907)

Comment: A neologism may be repeated but that does not give it a valid existence within language.

Comment: I appreciate the effort that you found the examples. I've already found the word as I've mentioned in the OP. I didn't search how common it was because it wasn't in any credible dictionaries. However, a fictional term might not have found its way to dictionaries yet. I'll wait for a while to see if there will be more answers.

Comment: I answered only to provide some examples of use should you decide to go with it. You can also use quote marks, as some of the examples do.

Comment: **Unsoul** would be another option; a comparison with *desoul* would be interesting. Shakespeare used *unsex* to remove sex and there are verbs such as *unclothe* and *unman*.

Comment: @StuartF Not bad IMO. As long as the reader can get the meaning from context,  I think the writer has leeway and can choose or invent--there isn't a standard word.

Answer (score 2):

***Unsoul*** is a verb I've missed apparently and it is even in *OED* unlike desoul. *OED* lists three senses of the verb *unsoul*, and the relevant second sense is listed as below:

> To deprive of soul; to make soulless. Also const. *of.*

In many examples provided, it is used figuratively; however I've found a fictional example as well:

> It operates by "unsouling" the body and disembodying the soul. Like a vampire, this demon sucks up the soul into itself, and will eventually kill man after having first made him strong enough to destroy the rest of the Cosmos. 
> <sub>*[Humanism and Naturalism: A Comparative Study of Ernest Seillière, Irving Babbitt and Paul Elmer More.](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ho9UAAAAYAAJ&q=%22unsouling%20the%22&dq=%22unsouling%20the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiux7387qf5AhUEwoUKHbbrBPQQ6AF6BAgGEAI)* By Folke Leander. (Göteborg: Wettergren and Kerbers Förlag. 1937. Pp. vi + 227. Price Kr. 8.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

*Eviscerate*, in its figurative sense, might work here:

> *The creature eviscerated him and turned him into an empty shell of flesh and blood, shortly destined to become dust.*

> **eviscerate,** *v.*
>
> **2.** In various figurative applications.
>
> **a.** To draw out what is vital or essential in (any thing); to elicit the ‘pith’ or essence of. *rare*.
>  <sub>1664    J.
> EVELYN *Sylva* Pref. to Rdr.    They..as it were eviscerating
> Nature..have collected innumerable Experiments, etc.</sub>
> <sub>1768    W. BLACKSTONE *Comm. Laws Eng.* III. 205    To
> prevent fraud and chicane, and eviscerate the very truth of the
> title.</sub>
>  <sub>1872    O. W. Holmes *Poet at
> Breakfast-table* ix    Some single point I could..eviscerate and
> leave..settled.</sub>
>
> **b.** To empty *of* vital contents; to deprive (an argument, institution, enactment, etc.) of all that gives it value or
> importance.
>  <sub>1834    *Blackwood’s Mag.* 36 329   
> France was eviscerated of all the nobler organs which once gave it a
> European existence.</sub>
>  <sub>1845    W. SEWELL *Hawkstone*
> I. 79    The hymn..was..one of Watts’ which Mr. Priestley had
> previously eviscerated of all peculiar doctrines.</sub>
>  <sub>1881
>    *Daily News* 15 Feb. 2/1    Amendments intended to
> eviscerate the clause were moved by Dr. Commins..and others.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Comment: It strangely fits but the literal sense is: "to remove one or all of the organs from the inside of a body, to disembowel".  Our inner organs are the vital parts so the figurative sense is an allusion to the vital parts, thus it can be interpreted as the soul. +1

Comment: Explore also the *essence* / *essential* aspect of the word:  “something that exists, esp. a spiritual or immaterial entity.”

Answer (score 0):

There are (or were) a number of words that can be used from the perspective of a soul no longer having a body.

### Disembody

The most prominent would be to [disembody](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disembody). This is especially common in its adjective form.

### Unbody

There's also [unbody](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unbody), which is certainly uncommon. Nevertheless, Chaucer: "The fate wold his soule sholde vnbodye" from Troilus and Criseyde (c1374).

### Uncorse?

Historically, there was even *[uncorse](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED48082)*, from *cors*, the word for body (dead or alive). It's unfortunately unlikely to be understood by modern audiences and hasn't seen much (any) usage in hundreds of years.

From the Chronicle of [John Hardying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hardyng) — 1543(1464):

> Afore he dyed he did full sore repent…Afore his soule was passed and vncorced.

My translation: "Before he died he did fully, sorely repent... Before his soul passed and was uncorsed."

Comment: Clever! I haven't thought from the perspective of a soul no longer having a body. It is a useful answer. It reminded me of Sauron from Tolkien Universe. His body was destroyed, but his spirit was not diminished in the story. +1

Comment: disembody is completely different. It is not the soul that doesn't have a body. It's a person who doesn't have one.

Answer (score -2):

"**Smote**" may be acceptable due to its religious connotations. Anecdotally I have also seen it used frequently in fantasy literature in a similar context to the original sentence, and it reads well to me.

> The creature smote him and turned him into an empty shell of flesh and
> blood, shortly destined to become dust.

Comment: Smiting *may* connote damage that's not strictly physical, but you can certainly smite someone without removing their soul.

Comment: Good answer as a new contributor +1. However, it would be better if you can add relevant dictionary definitions and the relevant examples in a similar context that you have found.